# Jquery Alert after DD operation

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee

I have a form in which the data is passing to store in the db. After the Db operation I need to show a fancy J query Alert whether Db operation success of failure. How can I do this?

Comment: More details needed. How are you submitting the form? Via AJAX? Show us the code so far.

Answer (score 0):

make 2 flag(say 0 and 1) for DB operation. 1 for SUCCESS one for NONSUCCESS. When DB operations are successfully completed then pass 1 to call or initialize the Jquery alert for success and same for unsucess.

Like

```
if(DB==1){
     jAlert("SUCCESS");
}
if(DB==0){
     jAlert("UNSUCCESS");
}
```